# truffle-contract: Contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

Tags: contract-invocation, truffle-contract, quorum, networkid

I am running a private network and would like to use `truffle-contract` to interact with the contracts. Unfortunately it gives me this error:

```
Error: Contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
```

I am using `truffle-contract@3.0.7` and here is how I set up my code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3-quorum');
const truffleContract = require('truffle-contract');

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:22000'));

const ContractJSON = require('./build/contracts/Contract.json');

var MyContract = truffleContract({
    abi: ContractJSON.abi,
    unlinked_binary: ContractJSON.bin,
    address: ContractJSON.address
});
MyContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

MyContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {  
    return instance.myMethod(
        web3.utils.toHex('31ad646cf39d485d8df7'), 
        Number(100), 
        Number(12345));
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => { console.log(err); });
```

I also tried `MyContract.setNetwork(10);`, whereby 10 matches `net.version` output (geth console) or also chainId in the genesis.json. Unfortunately without luck.

Comment: Can you try passing the whole artifact file to truffleContract, ie something like `var MyContract = truffleContract(ContractJSON)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the whole artifact file to `truffleContract` make it work, ie something like

```
...
const ContractJSON = require('./build/contracts/Contract.json');
var MyContract = truffleContract(ContractJSON)
...
```